# Rails 3 & paperclip - path for storing images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, paperclip

I try to set up the path for storing images with using Paperclip plugin.

In my model I set the path as:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/gallery/:user_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:url => "/gallery/:user_id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

But the images are storing to the directory called **"/user_id"**, not to the directory "**1**" (as the ID of user) - what I am doing wrong? Forgot I on anything important?

**EDIT - THE SOLUTION:**

If you have a model (eg. `photo`) and you want save the images to folder that called as ID of another model (eg. `user`), you have to add to `config/initializers` the file `paperclip.rb` with following content:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.interpolations[:user_id] = proc do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.user_id # or whatever you've named your User's login/username/etc. attribute
end
```

After this update is needed to restart WEBRick yet.

PS - an assumption is the relation between these two models.

Thank you

Comment: could you give us some details about the setup?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new syntax to do this, in case somebody need it:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :user_id do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.user_id
end
```